# Url rewriting first parameter in a search query

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I apologize if there is a question like this out there, but after 1 hour of trying things and searching on here i forced myself to ask...

So what i am working with is a search query with 8 parameters, some of them might not be submitted and some might, depending on the advanced search form.

So i have this rewrite thing that makes it so that if users go to {link}/search the real link is {link}?url=search

Anyways, what i now want to do is make it so that when users go to {link}/search and have searched with for example ?q=somethinghere&category=somecategory&location=losangeles

it works just like it does with {link}/index.php?url=search?q=somethinghere&category=somecategory&location=losangeles

If it helps, here is all i got right now in my htaccess rewrite thing

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(|/)$ index.php?url=$1 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(|/)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule looks ok just add the QSA (Query String Append) to append querystring to the destination url

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```